# Java 'getLocalName()' returns null even with 'setNamespaceAware(true)'

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have the following sample xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root attr1="value1"/>
```

The following Java sample demonstrates the issue I am facing:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Attr;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;

public class XMLClass {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // path to xml file
    String filename = "src/resources/xmlfile.xml";

    DocumentBuilderFactory db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    // this only helps for attr1 but not attr2
    db.setNamespaceAware(true);

    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(filename);
    Document doc = db.newDocumentBuilder()
            .parse(input);

    Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();

    // create an additional attribute
    root.setAttribute("attr2", "value2");

    NamedNodeMap nnm = root.getAttributes();

    // The attribute name and value is correct
    // for the attr1, however, the name for
    // attr2 is null
    for (int i = 0; i < nnm.getLength(); i++) {
        Attr a = (Attr) nnm.item(i);
        String name = a.getLocalName();
        String value = a.getValue();

        System.out.println("name: " + name + "; value: " + value);
    }

    System.exit(0);
}


}
```

The output is:

```
name: attr1; value: value1
name: null; value: value2
```

I have searched the Web and the only advise I found was to use `setNamespaceAware(true)`, as I had already done in my code. This ensures that the attribute name for `attr1`, which is defined in the XML file, is returned correctly by `getLocalName()`. However, the attribute name `attr2`, which is set in the code via `setAttribute()` is null, although the value is correctly retrieved.

What is the reason for this behaviour and what is the proper way to solve my issue?

Comment: So you are parsing an XML file and modifying it at the same time?

Comment: @AdamSiemion Yes, and later I save it under a different name. The saved file has the correct names and values.

Comment: The documentation for [getLocalName()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.xml/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getLocalName()) and [setAttribute](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.xml/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) contain the answers to your question.  Namely, use [`setAttributeNS`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.xml/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#setAttributeNS(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String))`(null, "attr2", "value2")`.

Comment: @VGR Thanks, I found that out, too, after some further research. If you make this comment into an answer I will accept it, nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for [getLocalName()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.xml/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getLocalName()) says:

> For nodes of any type other than `ELEMENT_NODE` and `ATTRIBUTE_NODE` and nodes created with a DOM Level 1 method, such as `Document.createElement()`, this is always `null`.

And the documentation for [setAttribute](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.xml/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) says:

> To set an attribute with a qualified name and namespace URI, use the `setAttributeNS` method.

So, setting an attribute value will not set the local name unless you explicitly set a namespaced attribute with [setAttributeNS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.xml/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#setAttributeNS(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)):

```
root.setAttributeNS(null, "attr2", "value2");
```